# Creating a folder and deleting on a FTP server with RCurl

Tags: r, ftp, rcurl

With the `ftpUpload()` function of the `RCurl` package for R, I am able to upload a file on a FTP server. But how to create a new folder on the FTP server from R ? And how to delete a file or a folder ?

Comment: You may need to show what you have already tried in a reproducible example for people to get motivated to try and help you further.

Comment: @SimonO101 I have search during a couple of years, but I have not find anything to try.

Comment: Try figuring out how to do it with curl first, then figure out how to do it with Rcurl. Googling "delete file ftp curl" gives some useful results.

Comment: @hadley Thanks. But the RCurl documentation is like chinese for me. I think it would take me less time to find how to do with a system command (which I could easily run from R).

Comment: @hadley's comment is pretty much spot on. Everything in RCurl eventually points to `curlPerform`, which is basically just a direct wrapper for curl system calls.

Comment: Ok @Thomas. I don't know what is curl and my request is not urgent. If nobody provides an example then later I will try to find how to do.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me, but the correct quote command is DELE, not DELETE!
Here a list of commands http://www.nsftools.com/tips/RawFTP.htm

So try:

```
curlPerform(url="ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/", quote="DELE file.txt", userpwd = "user:pass")
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to create a new folder, you can simply include the full path when you upload a file, and enable the ftp.create.missing.dirs option:

```
.opts <- list(ftp.create.missing.dirs=TRUE)
user <- "yourlogin"
pwd <- "yourpassword"

RCurl::ftpUpload(what = "filename.txt", to = "ftp://yourserver.com:21/newFolder/filename.txt", userpwd = paste(user, pwd, sep = ":"), .opts = opts)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using curlPerform to send quote commands. Try something like this to delete. You may have to look up the actual ftp commands for creating a dir and deleting a file.

```
curlPerform(url="ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/", quote="DELETE file.txt", userpwd = "user:pass")
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a folder, use curlPerform("ftphost",quote="MKD foldername",userpwd="user:pass"). To delete a file, use curlPerform("ftphost",quote="DELETE filename",userpwd="user:pass").
Depending on the FTP server, you may have to use mkdir instead of MKD and del or DELE instead of DELETE. It depends on the server.